# Word "mail merge" DOCTYPE

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm trying to automatically generate Word documents. The necessary data is entering Word through custom document properties, coming from a third party program. Now I'd need to use conditionals on that data (e.g. if property X contains value Y, print string Z here, else string A).

I've been trying to do that using the conditional features of the mail merge feature[1], but I can't get it to work. Is there anyone who has succeeded here? VBA is unfortunately impossible due to constraints of the environment.

[1]: using Word's "magic braces" ```
{ IF { DOCPROPERTY Myname } =  "val" "output value if true" "output value if false" }

Comment: You have the right syntax. What happens if you click on this field (with field results showing rather than field codes) and press **`F9`** *(`Fn`+`F9` on many computers)*?

Answer (score 1):

After inserting《Myname》Merge Field, select it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to add {} for `{MERGEFIELD Myname}`, as shown below.
Please note that the {} symbol must be added by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F9</kbd>.

[image]

Then select all Merge Fields and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, then <kbd>F9</kbd> to preview results.
You could also refer to the method in [Field codes: IF field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-if-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

On some computers anytime you use a function key you need to also press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.